# Number of ways the letters of two k-letter words can match

Tags: combinatorics

$M(k) :=$ the number of ways the letters of two (ordered) k-letter words can match.

$M(1) = 2$: the single letters of the two words are either matching or not.

$M(2) = 12$:

$$\begin{array}{ c|c c }
      & A & A \\\hline
    B & \circ & \circ \\
    B & \circ & \circ \\
\end{array}
\begin{array}{ c|c c }
      & A & A \\\hline
    A & \bullet & \bullet \\
    A & \bullet & \bullet \\
\end{array}
\begin{array}{ c|c c }
      & A & B \\\hline
    A & \bullet & \circ \\
    B & \circ & \bullet \\
\end{array}
\begin{array}{ c|c c }
      & A & B \\\hline
    B & \circ & \bullet \\
    A & \bullet & \circ \\
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ c|c c }
      & A & B \\\hline
    A & \bullet & \circ \\
    C & \circ & \circ \\
\end{array}
\begin{array}{ c|c c }
      & A & B \\\hline
    B & \circ & \bullet \\
    C & \circ & \circ \\
\end{array}
\begin{array}{ c|c c }
      & A & B \\\hline
    C & \circ & \circ \\
    A & \bullet & \circ \\
\end{array}
\begin{array}{ c|c c }
      & A & B \\\hline
    C & \circ & \circ \\
    B & \circ & \bullet \\
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{ c|c c }
      & A & A \\\hline
    A & \bullet & \bullet \\
    B & \circ & \circ \\
\end{array}
\begin{array}{ c|c c }
      & A & A \\\hline
    B & \circ & \circ \\
    A & \bullet & \bullet \\
\end{array}
\begin{array}{ c|c c }
      & A & B \\\hline
    A & \bullet & \circ \\
    A & \bullet & \circ \\
\end{array}
\begin{array}{ c|c c }
      & A & B \\\hline
    B & \circ & \bullet \\
    B & \circ & \bullet \\
\end{array}$$

How to calculate $M(k)$?

The upper bound for $M(k)$ is obviously $2^\left(k^2\right)$, because each letter from the first word is either matching with any of the letters of the second word or not, but not all "match patterns" are possible.

Based on computer simulation $M(3) = 128, M(4) = 2100, M(5) = 48032$.

Two example matches for k=5 out of the 48032:

$$\begin{array}{ c|c c }
      & A & B & C & C & D\\\hline
    A & \bullet & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ \\
    A & \bullet & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ \\
    B & \circ & \bullet & \circ & \circ & \circ \\
    B & \circ & \bullet & \circ & \circ & \circ \\
    C & \circ & \circ & \bullet & \bullet & \circ \\
\end{array}\begin{array}{ c|c c }
      & A & B & C & D & E\\\hline
    A & \bullet & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ \\
    A & \bullet & \circ & \circ & \circ & \circ \\
    B & \circ & \bullet & \circ & \circ & \circ \\
    C & \circ & \circ & \bullet & \circ & \circ \\
    D & \circ & \circ & \circ & \bullet & \circ \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Different type of letters? 30?

Comment: Well, I'm only interested in lowish Ks, but let's restrict the letters to (let's say) latin letters (A-Z).

Comment: But if it helps, we can assume an infinite alphabet.

Comment: Oh! Ok, I understand your problem now, it is more complicated that I tought in first place :p. But the upper bound is $(2L)^2$ that are the number of squared matrices with $0s$ and $1s$ of $L*L$ dimensions.

Comment: yes, sry, I was wrong... it is $2^{2L}$ the opposite exponentiation :p

Comment: This can take me some time so I removed the answer by now. I have 2 different approach, one harder than other. I will post one when it will be ready.

Comment: So actually I've found some paper based on the integer sequence I just generated by the computer. https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C12%2C128%2C2100%2C48032  http://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.1299v3 It's only 12 pages but I can't asses the hardness of it. And funny, they also provide enumeration, which I also wanted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17552/discussion-between-masacroso-and-tamas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time trying to solve definitively the problem @Tamas finally [found a paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.1299) with the "solution".

Based on the calculated values of $M$ given by a computer program that checked all possible matrices, $M(n)$ gives the https://oeis.org/A014235 series. It's formula is therfore is $\sum_{k=0}^{n} k! * S(n+1, k+1)^2$ where $S$ is the function to get the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

The general case for a matrix of $n\times m$ is $\sum_{k=0}^{\min(n,m)} k!\cdot S(m+1, k+1) S(n+1, k+1)$

The problem discussed in the referenced [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.1299) of the series can be directly applied to this problem. (On the link provided the answer is the section 3.1 named "$\Gamma$-avoiding matrices".)

Comment: Oh, I see.. I will fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the transcript! I found some more errors since yesterday. The canonical AABAA for W1 is not represented in the formula. I.e. the first occurrence of each letter should be ascending, but the second and the rest occurance of these letters have no constraints. Second problem that W2 have indeed at most B+1 different letters, but have an additional constraint: it must have at least B-1 letters present fromt the original B different letters of W1, otherwise ABCD x EEEE and AABB x CCCC will count the same matrix twice.

Comment: We might first select the non matching rows & cols ($E_1$ and $E_2$ respectively) then solve the problem where each letter must match with at least one letter from the other word. It keeps the problem symmetric for the words. (The alphabet then must be the same for both) $\mathfrak M(L_1, L_2)=\sum\limits_{E_1=0}^{L_1}\sum\limits_{E_2=0}^{L_2} {L_1 \choose E_1}{L_2 \choose E_2} \mathfrak N(L_1-E_1,L_2-E_2)$

Comment: It really boils down to how to calculate the number of canonical words with length L. I.e. where the first occurrence of all letters forms the ABC... series.